# Align horizontal tree node labels in pstree

Tags: pstricks, pst-tree

I'm trying to create a listing, with pstricks, that has its entrys on top of the line. Unlike normal tree nodes/leaves, the entry is not at the end.

The clue is now to left (or right) align all entries on an imaginary vertical line.

It might be possible, that array is a better alternative. If so, please argue for that.

My MWE looks like this (without alignment, the line indicates the alignment I want). Picture below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-tree}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    \rput(0,0){
        \pstree{\Tdot}{%Top Root
            \pstree{%first line down
                \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=3cm]{%first line right
                    \Tp
                }{
                \Tp
                \taput[labelsep=3pt,tnpos=l]{Level A}
            }
        }{    
        \pstree{%second line down
                \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=3cm]{%second line right
                    \Tp
                }{
                    \Tp
                    \taput[labelsep=3pt,tnpos=l]{LevelLevel B}
                }
            }{
                \Tp%third line down
            }
        }
    }
}

%Align along this line..
\psline(-1,3)(-1,-2)
\uput[ur](-1,3){align here}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\def\Txt#1{\makebox[2cm][l]{#1}}
\begin{document}

        \pstree{\Tdot}{%Top Root
            \pstree{%first line down
                \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=3cm]{%first line right
                    \Tp
                }{
                \Tp
                \taput[labelsep=3pt]{\Txt{Level A}}
            }
        }{    
        \pstree{%second line down
                \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=3cm]{%second line right
                    \Tp
                }{
                    \Tp
                    \taput[labelsep=3pt]{\Txt{LevelLevel B}}
                }
            }{
                \Tp%third line down
            }
        }
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, I would have never come up with the makebox trick. Thank you!